# How to access WIFI passwords in android backup?

Tags: backup, restore, wifi-password

I have backups from my previous android phone in my Samsung Account as well as in my Google Account. I do not want to restore the entire backup to my new phone, I just want to read the passwords stored in Wifi backups. (My old phone is damaged.)